# Combine 3 different GSheets to one GDS table

Tags: google-sheets, reporting, looker-studio

I have 3 people working on different restricted tables with the same header and same structure and I would like to combine the tables into one GDS table.

https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/59556470/how-to-merge-multiple-datasets?hl=en

I tried to use Blend data in GDS and used Youtube but it seems like I am not smart enough. To combine all 3 tables into one table in GDS.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5zpJNMsJio instead of using the array GSheet function I would like to combine the 3 tables into GDS

TL;DR: 3 GSheet tables with roughly 300 lines combined into one GDS table with 900 lines ;)

Can somebody please help me :)

I used to blend data but instead of combining the 3 tables I got 1 table with a couple of headers

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps to blend and vertical stack the data of 3 separate datasets.

connect your 3 datasets to datastudio
create a blend with `Full Outer Join` of the 3 data sets as shown in the screenshot below

use [`COALESCE`](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10522032?hl=en&ref_topic=10490726) Fx on both the dimension & metric to stack them as single dataset

**dimension**

```
COALESCE(Sales Person (Table 1),Sales Person (Table 2),Sales Person (Table 3))
```

**metric**

```
COALESCE(Sales (Table 1),Sales (Table 2),Sales (Table 3))
```

[image]

-

[image]